# Why does this html table get extra cells?

Tags: html, html-table

I don't have much experience with html, but I tried to make a simple table and I get extra cells in it, I don't know why.
Here is the code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"> hi <td>
        <td colspan="3"> hi <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> hi <td>
        <td colspan="5"> hi <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I expect this to have two rows with 2 cells in each, in first row first cell is bigger, and in second row second cell is bigger. But for some reason I get 4 cells in each row, like this:

[image].

Comment: Why are you using colspan=5 + 3 in a table that has only two columns? If you get rid of that, it'll work.

Comment: Why are you having those colspans there if you are looking to have just 2 columns in both rows? Removing the colspans will remove the extra cells as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't terminate your `<td>`.... You need a `</td>` at the end.

### Working Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GFdP6/3/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"> hi </td>
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td>
        <td colspan="5"> hi </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Furthermore

If you want it to look like you'd expect, you will have to set some widths on your td's like I did in the fiddle.

Comment: +1 - Took me a few seconds to realise what you'd changed. Sometimes it's really hard to spot the obvious, nice catch :P

Answer (score 1):

You have used TD Start Tags when you want TD End Tags. So you have 4 TD elements in each row instead of 2. (Note that the end tag for TD is *optional* so this is valid).

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo...  The closing TD tags are missing.

```
<table border="1"> 
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="5"> hi --> close your tags here --> </td>
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td> 
        <td colspan="5"> hi </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing tags for `<td>.`

```
<table border="1"> 
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="5"> hi </td> 
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="3"> hi </td> 
        <td colspan="5"> hi </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```